# Как получить количество массив объектов после применения фильтра?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Каким образом получить массив объектов после фильтрации в Яндекс.Картах? Пробую так:

```
flats.setFilter(filters);
myMap.geoObjects.add(flats);
alert('Количество отфильтрованных объектов на карте: ' + flats.objects.overlays.getLenght());
```

Как будто неверно указан overlay

Аналогичный вопрос в клубе API Яндекс.Карты: https://yandex.ru/blog/mapsapi/kak-uznat-kolichestvo-elementov-posle-primeneniya-setfilter

Пример из документации: https://tech.yandex.com/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/objectManager.OverlayCollection-docpage/#getLength 
Если делать как в примере, то выводит 0.

Comment: Можете привести более конкретный пример что не работает?

Comment: Есть массив из 100 квартир с данными по ним (площадь, цена и т.д.). 
Я устанавливаю фильтр: 1 млн. < цена < 2 млн. Таких квартир оказалось, скажем, 50. 
Произвожу отображение этих 50 квартир на карте.
И необходимо получить количество этих квартир и массив из них.

Общее количество квартир получить получается: flats.objects.getLength(). А вот количество отфильтрованных - нет.

Comment: Что значит "не получается"? Возвращается неправильное значение или код падает с ошибкой? Если вы соберете пример на jsfiddle (или прямо здесь,, в вопросе), то ответить на ваш вопрос будет гораздо проще.

Comment: Виноват. Возвращает 0.

Comment: Оверлеи создаются асинхронно, поэтому их 0. Вы хотите количество отфильтрованных элементов вообще или количество видимых на карте отфильтрованных элементов?

Comment: Количество и массив отфильтрованных объектов вообще. Знаю, что есть методы getAll(), getLenght().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете получить массив отфильтрованных объектов сами по состоянию [`isFilteredOut`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/ObjectManager-docpage/#getObjectState):

```js
objectManager.getAll().filter(function(x) {
  return !objectManager.getObjectState(x.id).isFilteredOut;
})
```

Comment: Оно! Большое спасибо!